# Knockout JS failed to update observableArray

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-templating

So I'm trying to add content to an observable array, but it doesn't update. The problem is not the first level content, but the sub array. It's a small comments section.
Basically I've this function to declare the comments

```
function comment(id, name, date, comment) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.date = ko.observable(date);
    self.comment = ko.observable(comment);
    self.subcomments = ko.observable([]);
}
```

I've a function to retrieve the object by the `id` field

```
function getCommentByID(id) {
    var comment = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.comments(), function (comment) {
        return comment.id === id;
    });
    return comment;
}
```

This is where I display my comments

```
<ul style="padding-left: 0px;" data-bind="foreach: comments">
    <li style="display: block;">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <br>
        <span data-bind="text: date"></span>
        <br>
        <span data-bind="text: comment"></span>
        <div style="margin-left:40px;">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: subcomments">
                <li style="display: block;">
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    <br>
                    <span data-bind="text: date"></span>
                    <br>
                    <span data-bind="text: comment"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <textarea class="comment" placeholder="comment..." data-bind="event: {keypress: $parent.onEnterSubComment}, attr: {'data-id': id }"></textarea>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And `onEnterSubComment` is the problematic event form

```
self.onEnterSubComment = function (data, event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
        var obj = getCommentByID(parseInt(id));
        var newSubComment = new comment(0, self.currentUser, new Date(), event.target.value);
        obj.subcomments().push(newSubComment);
        event.target.value = "";
    }
    return true;
};
```

It's interesting, because when I try the same operation during initialization(outside of any function) it works fine

```
var subcomment = new comment(self.commentID, "name1", new Date(), "subcomment goes in here");
self.comments.push(new comment(self.commentID, "name2", new Date(), "some comment goes here"));
obj = getCommentByID(self.commentID);
obj.subcomments().push(subcomment);
```

If anyone can help me with this, cause I'm kind of stuck :(

Comment: quick shot: maybe `self.subcomments = ko.observableArray([])` instead of `self.subcomments = ko.observable([])`? Demo on jsfiddle is always a good idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

1st, you have to declare an observable array:

```
self.subcomments = ko.observableArray([]);
```

2nd, you have to use the observable array methods, instead of the array methods. I.e. if you do so:

```
obj.subcomments().push(subcomment);
```

If `subcomments` were declared as array, you'd be using the `.push` method of `Array`. But, what you must do so that the observable array detect changes is to use the `observableArray` methods. I.e, do it like this:

```
obj.subcomments.push(subcomment);
```

Please, [see this part of observableArray documentation: Manipulating an observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#manipulating-an-observablearray):

> observableArray exposes a familiar set of functions for modifying the contents of the array and notifying listeners.
>
> All of these functions are equivalent to running the native JavaScript array functions on the underlying array, and then notifying listeners about the change

Comment: Thank you very much, what I ended doing is changing in comment object declaration self.subcomments = ko.observable([]); to self.subcomments = ko.observableArray([]); and then obj.subcomments.push(newSubComment) worked like a charm.